# Timepicker not working in webpage

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, timepicker

Jquery Time picker is not working in my webpage.

http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/

I'm using the above Timepicker.

```
<script src="Script/JQueryTimePicker/include/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Script/JQueryTimePicker/include/jquery.ui.core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Script/JQueryTimePicker/include/jquery.ui.position.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Script/JQueryTimePicker/include/jquery.ui.widget.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Script/JQueryTimePicker/include/jquery.ui.tabs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Script/JQueryTimePicker/include/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<link href="Script/JQueryTimePicker/jquery.ui.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Script/JQueryTimePicker/jquery.ui.timepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tb_DelTime').timepicker();
    });
    </script>



<span class="span">
    <label class="Informlabel">
        Del Time :
    </label>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="tb_DelTime" runat="server" Width="60%"></asp:TextBox>
</span>
```

Can you Help me ??

Comment: Please post your html too. Or even better, create a js fiddle

Comment: its working fine with me..no probs at all... considering you have written corresponding HTML for this

Comment: I have posted the Html. Datepicker is also not working in my page

Comment: Do you use MasterPage? If so, then client ID of TextBox will differ, from one you see here. And you should do it this way: $('#<%= tb_DelTime.ClientId %>').timepicker();

Comment: @Uriil Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept It. Can I change the Theme of this timepicker to `Smoothness`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use :

```
$('[id*=tb_DelTime]').timepicker();
```

Answer (score 1):

To work you must get the rendered id as:

```
$('#<%=tb_DelTime.ClientID%>').timepicker();
```